# Append() and pop() troubles

Tags: python

When I try to pop X amount of cards from a list it says that i can't pop from an empty list, but im sure then list should be full! Is there another way to do this

```
while len(dogs) > 0:                                      
    for i in range(0,CardAmount):                         
        playersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))                   
        computersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))
```

Full code:
https://dumptext.com/4HhdTFRj

Dogs.txt file:
https://dumptext.com/BPDsU9Hl

Error in console:

```
playersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: you are checking `dogs` in the while loop, but then you have a for loop that doesn't check that. If `dogs` contain less elements than double the `CardAmount` (because inside the for loop you pop twice) you will have a problem (which is what you actually see). To solve it you can do the following check in the while loop: `while len(dogs) > 2*CardAmount:`

Comment: you are `pop`ping twice and checking once. this is a bad way to do things

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of the while loop you are giving `CardAmount` number of cards to `playersDeck` and `CardAmount` number of cards to `computerDeck`, so you need at least `2*CardAmount` to be able to do the loop.

So instead of checking `if len(dogs) > 0` you have to check `if len(dogs) >= 2*CardAmount` so you can do the loop

```
while len(dogs) >= 2*CardAmount:                                      
    for i in range(0, CardAmount):                         
        playersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))                   
        computersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))
```

By the way, instead of doing the pop in a loop you could just do:

```
while len(dogs) >= 2*CardAmount:
    playersDeck.append(dogs[:2*CardAmount:2])    # even poitions
    computerDeck.append(dogs[1:2*CardAmount:2])  # odd positons
    dogs = dogs[2*CardAmount:]                   # update dogs
```